# Allow in-app Purchases to be Earned For Free

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, in-app-purchase, windows-phone-8

in my app I plan to have the supplemental content in my game available as an in-app purchase. However, I also want to be able to have it so that they can unlock the content without having to pay for it by doing a large accomplishment of some sort. How would I go about this and is it possible to do it in the Store library?

Answer (score 1):

You could have to create two products for each unlockable content, one free (that becomes available after that accomplishment) and a paid one (that can be bought from within the app). Having either one results in the same unlocked content.